# How do I move/create the nav of my magento webshop in the top

Tags: magento, nav

Hi all I'm new here and definitely new with Magento 1.9. I'm currently doing an internship in this company where my job is to make the design of the webshop be something like (screenshot_1[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zisGE.png) ) and this is how it should look [Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEPqy.jpg) So yea I am actually a designer but I work with Html and Css those are the only two languages I have studied at the moment so i dont understand anything from xml and phtml nor php. I have access to the back-end and FTP of the website just want to make it look like screenshot_2. The nav is really annoying because it only appears on the left or right side and i have no knowledge of the 3 other languages. pls help

Comment: Insert your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to magneto root folder
step-1 : app\design\frontend\Your theme pakage\your theme\template\page\html

if you use rwd theme then (app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html)

step-2 : Open header.phtml

step-3 : Move

```
<div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    </div>
```

in bottom where you need.

step-4 : Save